# Find last position in Python

Tags: python

I am learning Python and I am trying to resolve this problem without `len()` but I am still stuck. Here is a quiz explanation.

Define a procedure, find_last, that takes as input
two strings, a search string and a target string,
and returns the last position in the search string
where the target string appears, or -1 if there
are no occurrences.

Example: find_last('aaaa', 'a') returns 3

Make sure your procedure has a return statement.

Here is my code:

```
def find_last(search, target):
    target = search.find(target)
    while target:
        if target == -1:
            return target
        else:
            return target +1
    return target
```

Thank you.

Comment: you can use `rfind`

Comment: A loop is rather pointless if you have a `return` statement in every branch.

Answer (score 3):

You have several errors to fix:

1. `target` is the target string, not the position where you find it. You're overwriting that value.
2. You may need to call `search.find` multiple times
3. You only break out of the loop once `search.find` returns -1. Your function should then return the *previous* value returned by `search.find`.

Fixing each of those issues gives you

```
def find_last(search, target):
    # Find the first occurrence of target
    pos = search.find(target)

    # If you found something, keep looking for it until you don't
    # find it again
    while pos >= 0:
        # You found target once; now look for the next occurrence
        next_pos = search.find(target, pos + 1)
        if next_pos == -1:
            # no more targets, so stop looking
            break
        pos = next_pos 
    return pos
```

You could also use `return pos` instead of `break`.

---

As pointed out in the comments, though, `search.rfind(target)` already does what you want.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. To be clear `-1` means it does not find a target, correct?

Comment: Right; the indices in the string range from 0 upwards, so -1 can't be a valid index.